# What does PSX/TAS mean?

Tags: terminology

Typically in speedruns, I see in the title PSX and/or TAS, like a Metal Gear Solid 1 speedrun. What does both PSX and TAS mean?

Answer (score 8):

PSX is an abbreviation for the first Playstation. (Note that PSOne is something entirely different).

TAS stands for "Tool-Assisted Speedrun".

So together, PSX / TAS means a Tool-Assisted Speedrun of the Playstation version of Metal Gear Solid 1.

Comment: What's the difference between PSX and, say, using PS1?

Comment: What can be classified as a TAS?

Comment: Google seems to think [PSX is something different to the first PlayStation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSX_(video_game_console)) (they're wrong, clearly)

Comment: @Pyritie PSX is generally any Playstation 1 console, PSOne was the "slimmed down version" they released later in it's life. I don't agree that it's "entirely different".

Answer (score 1):

The term *PSX* is mainly used to refer to the first Sony PlayStation console. The abbreviation *PSX* is said to stand for *PlayStation Experimental*, which was the code name used during the console's development.

Delving more deeply into its history, it is said that *PSX* was to be a collaboration between Nintendo and Sony to create a CD-disk add-on for the Super Nintendo. This never came to fruition, and the concept for *PSX* became a new console all together. However, I have not taken the time to verify this as fact.

However! the term PSX is often used falsely for the original PlayStation; in fact, there is an actual device called the **PlayStation X** (wiki-link below). This was a Japan-only release of a PlayStation 2 with built-in video recorder. It sold rather poorly, and never made it to the west.

---

A *TAS* is a *tool assisted "speedrun"*. Meaning, this is a play-through of a video game, intended to complete it as fast as possible. *Tool assisted* refers to the possible emulation of the game, or use of slow-motion recording. Emulation glitches and/or exploits are allowed in these play-through sessions as well, which would not be possible in unassisted speedruns.

#### Sources:

- [PlaystationTrophies.org: Discussion on Origin of term 'PSX'](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/ps1-ps2-and-psp-discussion/108303-origins-term-psx.html)
- [Wikipedia: PSX Video Game Console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSX_(video_game_console))
- [Wikipedia: Tool-Assisted Speedrun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tool-assisted_speedrun)